# How do you write the law of total expectation for a conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I would like to compute $E[N|D]$, expectation of some random variable $N$ given that event $D$ occurs. In the outcome space, there are a set of disjoint events $B_1, B_2, B_3$.

How can I apply the law of total expectation to this $E[N|D]$?

I don't think it makes sense to write
$$
E[N|D] = E[N|D,B_1]P(B_1) + E[N|D,B_2]P(B_2) + E[N|D,B_3]P(B_3)  
$$

and I also don't think it makes sense to write (in part because it looks weird)
$$
E[N|D] = E[N|D|B_1]P(B_1) + E[N|D|B_2]P(B_2) + E[N|D|B_3]P(B_3)  
$$

The one thing I can think of doing is defining a random variable $M$ to be $N|D$. Then I can write it in a reasonable looking way:
$$
E[M] = E[M|B_1]P(B_1) + E[M|B_2]P(B_2) + E[M|B_3]P(B_3)  
$$

But how can I write this in terms of the original $N|D$?

Comment: What does " In the event space D, there are a set of disjoint events " mean?

Comment: @GrahamKemp sorry, I am not sure what I was trying to say there either. I changed it to “in the outcome space, there...” I think I may have tried to say that the disjoint events partitioned D earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N | D] = \mathbb{E}[N | D,B_1]\mathbb{P}(B_1 | D) + \mathbb{E}[N | D,B_2]\mathbb{P}(B_2 | D) + \mathbb{E}[N | D,B_3)\mathbb{P}(B_3 | D)
\end{align*}
This is because by definition of conditional expectation and the fact that $B_1,B_2,B_3$ are disjoint and together form the state space it holds that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N | D] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[N1_{D}]}{\mathbb{P}(D)} = 
\frac{\mathbb{E}[N1_{D}1_{B_1}] + \mathbb{E}[N1_{D}1_{B_2}] + \mathbb{E}[N1_{D}1_{B_3}]}{\mathbb{P}(D)}.
\end{align*}
Filling in the following expression for $j = 1,2,3$ yields the desired result:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N1_D1_{B_j}] = \mathbb{E}[N1_{D,B_j}] = \mathbb{E}[N | D,B_j]\mathbb{P}(D,B_j) = \mathbb{E}[N | D,B_j]\mathbb{P}(B_j | D)\mathbb{P}(D)
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you show where this expression came from?

Comment: I edited by answer, hope it now makes sense :)

Comment: Is the $1_D$ an indicator variable.

Comment: Yes, which is 1 if $D$ is true and 0 otherwise

Comment: It seems the formula is analogous to law of total probability except the $E$ is replaced with $P$?

Comment: If you would replace the expectations by probabilities in the formula the statement would still be correct, yes.